# Prove that if $A \mathbin{\triangle} C = B \mathbin{\triangle} C$, then $A = B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know what I'm supposed to do.

Since $A \mathbin{\triangle} C =  B \mathbin{\triangle} C \Longrightarrow (A-C) \cup (C - A) = (B- C) \cup (C - B)$

Prove $A$ is a subset of $B$:

Let $x$ be an element of A. Prove that $x$ is also an element of $B$ using the hypothesis that $(A-C) \cup (C - A) = (B - C) \cup (C - B)$

Prove $B$ is a subset of $A$:

Let $x$ be an element of $B$. Prove that $x$ is also an element of $A$ using the hypothesis that $(A-C) \cup (C - A) = (B- C) \cup (C - B)$.

But I don't know how to do it. Where should I start? Any suggestion would help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Take $a \in A$ and then look at the two cases: $a \in A \oplus C$ and $a \notin A \oplus C$. In both cases, there will be a contradiction if $a \notin B$. The latter half is essentially identical.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Full proof: $$(A\triangle C)\triangle C=A$$

Answer (score 3):

**aexl** has shown you how to proceed along the lines suggested in your question. For future reference here’s another possible approach.

- First show that symmetric difference is associative: for any sets $X,Y,Z$, $$X\mathbin{\triangle}(Y\mathbin{\triangle}Z)=(X\mathbin{\triangle}Y)\mathbin{\triangle}Z\;.$$
- Then show that for any set $X$, $X\mathbin{\triangle}X=\varnothing$ and $X\mathbin{\triangle}\varnothing=X$.
- Finally, note that if $A\mathbin{\triangle}C=B\mathbin{\triangle}C$, then $(A\mathbin{\triangle}C)\mathbin{\triangle}C=(B\mathbin{\triangle}C)\mathbin{\triangle}C$ and apply the first two facts.

Answer (score 2):

We show that $A \subset B$. Let $x \in A$. We consider the two cases $x \in C$ and $x \not\in C$.

1. If $x \in C$, then $x \in A \cap C$, so $x \not\in A \mathbin{\triangle} C$. Since $A \mathbin{\triangle} C = B \mathbin{\triangle} C$ we have $x \not\in B \mathbin{\triangle}C$. This means that $x \not\in B \setminus C$ and $x \not\in C \setminus B$. Since $x \in C$ and $x \not\in C \setminus B$, we must have $x \in B$.
2. If $x \not\in C$, then $x \in A \setminus C$, so $x \in A \mathbin{\triangle} C = B \mathbin{\triangle}C = B \setminus C \cup C \setminus B$. Since $x \not\in C$, we have $x \in B \setminus C$, so $x \in B$.

This shows $A \subset B$. Now do something similiar to show that $B \subset A$.

Comment: Thank you. It helps a lot.

Comment: You can get the actual set difference operator with `\setdifference`, and the symmetric difference operator with `\mathbin{\triangle}`.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: @aexl: You’re welcome. But I actually had a mental hiccup: the set difference operator is `\setminus`, not `\setdifference`!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an "abstract nonsense" proof:

Consider the "universe" $U:=A\cup B\cup C$, and identify subsets $X\subset U$ with their characteristic functions $1_X:\>U\to{\mathbb F}_2$ (the field of two elements).
Then$$1_{A\triangle C}=1_A+1_C\ .$$
From $A\triangle C=B\triangle C$ it then follows that $1_A+1_C=1_B+1_C$, and adding $1_C$ on both sides proves $1_A=1_B$.

Comment: That's a really nice and elegant solution!